# How do disable TCPDF version shown in the browser after PDF generation

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

When i generate the final  PDF the version is being displayed.
Is there any way to hide this information ?

I looked into the package documentation but i could not find anything.

[image]

This is information I do not want to share.
I checked if there are any functions but I can't find any.

Here is my code that i use to generate the pdf

```
 $pdf = new \TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    $pdfParams = $this->handlePageParamsByCoverSize($coverSize);
    $fontSize = $this->calculateFontSizeByCoverSize($coverSize);

    $scissorsIconPath = $this->fileLocator->locate('scissors.png');

    $pdf->SetFont(
        'helvetica',
        '',
        $fontSize
    );

    $pdf->AddPage('L', $pdfParams['format'], true, true);

    $pdf->Image(
        $coverPath,
        $pdfParams['cover']['x'],
        $pdfParams['cover']['y'],
        $pdfParams['cover']['w'],
        $pdfParams['cover']['h'],
        '',
        '',
        '',
        false,
        300,
        '',
        false,
        false,
        0
    );

    $pdf->Image(
        $scissorsIconPath,
        $pdfParams['scissorsIcon']['x'],
        $pdfParams['scissorsIcon']['y'],
        $pdfParams['scissorsIcon']['w'],
        $pdfParams['scissorsIcon']['h'],
        '',
        '',
        '',
        false,
        300,
        '',
        false,
        false,
        0
    );

    $filePath = '/covers/' .$coverName . '.pdf';
    $absFileName = $rootPath . $filePath;

    try {
        $pdf->Output($absFileName, 'F');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //Move on
    }

    if (file_exists($absFileName)) {
        $result = [
            'absPath' => $absFileName,
            'path' => $filePath,
        ];
    } else {
        $result = ['path' => 'error'];
    }

    return $result;
```

I am using the following package

```
"tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.4"
```

EDIT: Add code and more informations

Comment: Hey you are right. I did mean PDF. I added my code maybe it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

TCPDF seems to have to methods that might help you:

```
$tcpdf->SetCreator('My PDF-Generator tool');
$tcpdf->SetAuthor('Your name');
```

I haven't tried it by myself. I just had a look at the examples of the TCPDF documentation.

Comment: Great! I didn't see the `SetCreator()` method :-)

Comment: Sadly this does not work. I would have to override the static method. I mean the function do what they say set the creator and author. But i want to hide the version and what it was created with. (See picture)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use a free lib it's quite normal that you can't change that. It would be the same case with other products.

But if you search with a tool such as *ripgrep* in the source code, you'll see that this string is defined in `include/tcpdf_static.php` at line 127 and is called by `tcpdf.php` at two places:

```sh
rg "getTCPDFProducer"
```

Output:

```
include\tcpdf_static.php
127:    public static function getTCPDFProducer() {

tcpdf.php
9554:           $out .= ' /Producer '.$this->_textstring(TCPDF_STATIC::getTCPDFProducer(), $oid);
9649:           $xmp .= "\t\t\t".'<pdf:Producer>'.TCPDF_STATIC::_escapeXML(TCPDF_STATIC::getTCPDFProducer()).'</pdf:Producer>'."\n";
```

So if you really have to hide that, you should find a way to override that method, eventually apply a home-made patch or alter the generated file during or after generation.

Comment: Hey thank you. Does the code i provided now above change anything with your answer ?

Comment: No, your code won't change anything as this *Producer* is hard-coded in the library. If you installed the TCPDF lib yourself then just edit the `include/tcpdf_static.php` file. Best would be to create a patch file so that you can apply it again if you update the lib. I didn't take the time to see how you could override methods.

Comment: It seems that the `SetCreator()` method mentionned by René should solve your problem. Perhaps the *Producer* is shown in other places of the PDF properties. Good luck!

Comment: If you have to modify the 'producer' information, the best approach might be to extend the TCPDF class and override the _putinfo method. Then you have to use your class instead of TCPDF.